# Pass the node and create a dynamic view according to the nid? Drupal

Tags: drupal

I am creating a website in which users enter challenges through a form(created by CCK) so every challenge is a node. Now i want to pass the node id to a view so that the related information to that challenge can be displayed. That is when users click on the challenge name it should display all the information related to that challenge.

Please help

Thanks in advance
Kanwal

Additional info:

Thanks alot i have done that now the view is displaying the participants according to the argument i.e challenge node id but i have given the challenges url as challenge/[nid] instead of node/[nid]. If i keep it as node.[nid] it is picking up the view but not with challenge/[nid] even the pathe of the page is challenge/%. Any suggestions.

Thanks
Kanwal

Answer (score 1):

Can you explain a little more what you mean?

Creating a node view, adding a node id argument, and then creating a page display where you put a % in the path where you want the node to come in is fairly easy - give it a try.